# Testing on iOS 3.x using XCode 3.2.5

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios

I am using XCode 3.2.5. Due to a problem in Flurry I would realy like to test my apps on iOS 3.x, and since I updated all my test devices to 4.x I don't have any 3.x handsets left.

I have tried to follow this guide on how to install extra SDKs into newer xcodes, but when installing previouse SDKs and launcing them the simulation doesn't work. It notifies that the SDK failed to launch and lets me choose either to Quit, switch SDK or Relaunch the simulator.

Is there anything that I am forgetting or missing? Did someone managed to install earlier SDK's into 3.2.5?

Br,
Paul Peelen

Comment: Yes it's completely possible.  How are you launching your app?

Comment: Currently I have only been able to launch the iOS Simulator and choose the version using the "Hardware" menu. The 3.0 doesn't show up in XCode.

Comment: Much more importantly, What is the problem with Flurry ??? Need to know. Just put that into my code a few days ago, but haven't launched yet. Should I remove???

Comment: @Paul G. No, Flurry works great. But the 2.7 package has dependencys toward iOS4. at flurry.com you can read what framework and lib you should weak include. That should solve it of pre iOS4 devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing you can do is to get a used 1st/2nd gen iPod touch - they can be upgraded and downgraded just fine and are better for testing than the simulator.

But if you want to test with the old SDK anyway, assuming you have a disk image with an old SDK on it, you can install the previous SDK to somewhere other than the default directory of `/Developer` (e.g. something like `/Developer3.2`), then open your project in the copy of Xcode from `/Developer3.2/Applications`.

I don't know if there are any negative effects from doing this, but I often install beta SDKs to `/DeveloperBeta` for testing and haven't run into any problems.

Comment: True, I thought of that as well (the SDK part)... but the iOS4 uses some background functions which are unknown to previous SDK's... so I think it will fail on building. But... I'll give it a try. Thnx.

Comment: Just to clarify: I accepted this answer because it seems to me that the best and most secure way of doing this is to get an actual device to test on. I have tried and tried to get the older SDK's working with the latest XCode, but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem, but when you are building in Xcode make sure you change the active target to the older SDK.

To change the target, hit **alt-cmd-e**, switch to `Build`, and under `Base SDK` select the SDK you want.

Comment: I have, but the 3.0 doesn't show up there. They do show up in the simulator but won't launch.

Comment: Correction: Did got the 3.1.2 to show up now in XCode, but still have the same problem in the simulator. Both building to the 3.1.2 simulator, or launching the simulator manually.

Answer (score 0):

i think its important to know that the simulator is a "forgiver" a lot more then the device.
i have released an app that worked great when tested on simulator for 3.1 but crashed on lunching when downloaded...you defiantly don't want that to happen.

i have mailed apple about that and the official answer i got was to test it on real devices.
thats a problem if you cant afford buying the devices. but try to get them second hand.

just don't trust the simulator alone.

Comment: I agree, and this is usually what I do. But with having already 1x 3g, 2x 3gs and 2x iphone 4 I find buying yet another one a bit unnecessary. I'll try go get my hands on a iPod which seems to be a great solution.